# Parse array to http params Angular

Tags: angular, rest, http

Hi I would like to parse array with strings/enumerates into http params in Angular.

My example http request:

```
http://localhost:8091/air-quality?cities=cityname1,cityname2,cityname3
```

Example arrays (I didnt realize this yet but I will probably use the 2nd option):

```
cities = ["london", "madrid", "paris"] or cities = [LONDON, MADRID, PARIS]
```

request:

```
this.httpClient.get<number>(this.url, {params: params});
```

At this moment I can just build long string but it will look pretty bad. I tried use stringify but this method added %5D at the begin and end of params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array [join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp#:%7E:text=The%20join()%20method%20returns,not%20change%20the%20original%20array.):

```
let params = cities.join(',');
```

Comment: ohhh, that was pretty easy and solve my question, thank u